# First Name and Message Not shown on body of email

Tags: php, html, ajax, post, contact-form

i created a contact form php below, for some reason when I submit the entries, the First name shows up on the header but not the Body of the message. Same goes for message. Does anyone know the issue here?

```
  PHP



<?php
$field_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$field_last = $_POST['last_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_city = $_POST['cf_city'];
$field_state = $_POST['cf_state'];
$field_postal = $_POST['cf_postal'];
$field_country = $_POST['cf_country'];
$field_profession = $_POST['cf_profession'];
$field_industry = $_POST['cf_industry'];
$field_job = $_POST['cf_job'];
$field_linkedin = $_POST['cf_linkedin'];
$field_facebook = $_POST['cf_facebook'];
$field_instagram = $_POST['cf_instagram'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'membership@name.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_last."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'City: '.$field_city."\n";
$body_message .= 'State/Province: '.$field_state."\n";
$body_message .= 'Postal: '.$field_postal."\n";
$body_message .= 'Country: '.$field_country."\n";
$body_message .= 'Profession: '.$field_profession."\n";
$body_message .= 'Industry: '.$field_industry."\n";
$body_message .= 'Job: '.$field_job."\n";
$body_message .= 'LinkedIn: '.$field_linkedin."\n";
$body_message .= 'Facebook: '.$field_facebook."\n";
$body_message .= 'Instagram: '.$field_instagram."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('CourtSide House. Thank you for your submission');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to membership@name.com');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
    <?php}?>
```

HTML

```
<pre><form method="post" action="contact.php">
                    <p>Contact<p>
                    <hr>
                        <div class="row half">
                            <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="First Name*" name="first_name"></div>
                            <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Last Name*" name="last_name"></div>
                            <div class="12u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Email*" name="cf_email"></div>
                            <div class="4u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="City*" name="cf_city"></div>
                            <div class="4u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="State/Province*" name="cf_state"></div>
                            <div class="4u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Postal Code*" name="cf_postal"></div>
                            <div class="12u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Country*" name="cf_country"></div>
                            <div class="4u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Profession*" name="cf_profession"></div>
                            <div class="4u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Industry*" name="cf_industry"></div>
                            <div class="4u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Job Title*" name="cf_job"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p>Share Some Information About Yourself*<i><small class="small" id="small" style="font-size: 12px">(Please Place Link of Social Media Profile)</small></i></p>
                            <hr>
                        <div class="row half">


                            <div class="4u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile*" name="cf_linkedin"></div>
                            <div class="4u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Facebook Profile*" name="cf_facebook"></div>
                            <div class="4u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Instagram Profile*" name="cf_instagram"></div>
                            </div
                        ><div class="row half">
                            <div class="12u"><textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" ></textarea></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <ul class="actions">
                                    <li><input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append to the variable $body_message instead of overwriting it as you do the second time you call it.

```
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_last."\n";
```

should be

```
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'From: '.$field_last."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are confusing your e-mail clients with this:

```
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_last."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You're missing the concatenation operator on your variable assignment:

```
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_last."\n";
```

should be

```
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'From: '.$field_last."\n";
            ^^^^^
             HERE
```

2) You're message field is just called `message`:

```
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];
```

should be

```
$field_message = $_POST['message'];
```

Or change

```
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" >
```

to

```
<textarea name="cf_message" placeholder="Message" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Message is not showing because you are using wrong key when retrieving it.

Update with following:

```
$field_message = $_POST['message']; // Textarea's name is message not cf_message
```

Then, first name is not showing because you're overwriting `$body_message` right after you assign `$body_message` with `'From: '.$field_name."\n";`.

Update as follows:

```
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'From: '.$field_last."\n";  // Use .= not just =
```